# Jenkins git commit for specific branch triggers build jobs for other branches too

Tags: git, github, jenkins

We have a internal enterprise Github repo, and i have multiple feature branches.
I am facing a issue with triggering a build on a specific branch. 
I have configured jobs for each of the feature branches. There is one jenkins job for one feature branch.
The first time i commit a code, it also triggers builds for jobs with other branches.

Steps to reproduce the problem:

1.We have a internal Github for enterprise. For my repo, i have setup webhook for github as below

```
 Settings -> Webhooks & Services -> Services
 Select Jenkins (GitHub plugin) 
 Jenkins Hook Url: http://************/jenkins/github-webhook/
```

2.For my 3 branches in github repo : branch1, branch2, branch3, i created three jobs in jenkins:Job1, Job2, Job3 with SCM configured as below

```
Source Code Management:
Repo URL: git@********/********.git
Branches to Build: refs/heads/BRANCH_NAME

Build Trigger: Build when a change is pushed to GitHub
```

3.On committing code to my branch : branch1. It triggers all the 3 jobs in jenkins: Job1, Job2, Job3. 
   Note:This is the first time that the jobs were triggered.

4.On committing code for the second time to branch: branch1. It triggers only Job1 in jenkins.

It looks like first time all jobs are getting executed for the repo, irrespective of the branch.

Details on my jenkins setup: Jenkins Version: 1.565.1, GitHub plugin: 1.9.1

Any help/guidance to solve this issue is appreciated.

FYI: I tried steps listed http://kohsuke.org/2011/12/01/polling-must-die-triggering-jenkins-builds-from-a-git-hook/

Comment: Use the &branches=branchname on the URL: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66096593/3931589

Answer (score 0):

Make a script with the follow command (assuming your github SO is linux)

```
curl http://yourserver/jenkins/git/notifyCommit?url=<URL of the Git repository>
```

put this script in ./git/hooks

In your jenkins jobs change

**From**
"Build when a change is pushed to GitHub"

**To** "Poll SCM"

Don't create any schedule in Poll SCM