# Limit Jenkins Git polling to one branch

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, npm-version

Out current Jenkins Pipeline job is setup to build a branch checked out from Git. To do the checkout we use the SCM plugin:

```
  triggers {
    pollSCM scmpoll_spec: ''
  }

  checkout(
    poll: true,
    scm: [$class: 'GitSCM',
      branches: [[name: 'refs/heads/develop']],
      userRemoteConfigs: [
        [url: 'https://git-server/repo.git',
          name: 'origin',
          refspec: '+refs/heads/develop:refs/remotes/origin/develop',
          credentialsId: 'XXX']
      ],
      extensions: [
        [$class: 'WipeWorkspace'],
        [$class: 'CloneOption', honorRefspec: true, noTags: true, reference: '', shallow: false],
        [$class: 'LocalBranch', localBranch: 'develop']
      ],
      browser: [$class: 'GitList', repoUrl: 'https://git-server/gitlist/repo.git']
    ]
  )
```

During the build there is a call to `npm version patch` which updates the `package.json` file, commits and creates a tag locally. We then push this back to the server side git repository. In order to stop Jenkins from starting another build, we push with options and the post-receive hook ignores these pushes:

```
git push origin develop --follow-tags --push-option=nobuild
```

The post-receive hook on the server only POSTs to Jenkins when a user pushes as they wont use the options:

```
"https://jenkins-server/git/notifyCommit?url=https://git-server/repo.git"
```

This is all working wonderfully, however, problem is that when a developer commits to `feature` branch, a build for the `develop` branch is started. I'm guessing the following is the cause of the problem:

1. commit/push to `develop` branch
2. tag created during building `develop` branch
3. commit/push on `feature` branch
4. Jenkins sees new tag on develop `branch` and starts a build

So I'm looking for a way to either force Jenkins to only consider commits/pushes to a specific branch to trigger a specific build. Or to force Jenkins to ignore changes as part of a tag when considering starting a build.

Note, I found another SO post: [Jenkins git commit for specific branch triggers build jobs for other branches too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31886963/jenkins-git-commit-for-specific-branch-triggers-build-jobs-for-other-branches-to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though seemingly not in the documentation, looking for answers again I came across this Jenkins ticket: [JENKINS-29574 - notifyCommit branch parameter is ignored](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-29574). It seems you can add an extra parameter to the URL: `&branches=<branch-name>`

As part of the Git `post-receive` hook script I can find the branch name and use it as part of the POST:

```
https://jenkins-server/git/notifyCommit?url=https://git-server/repo.git&branches=develop
```

This now only kicks off the builds using that specific branch.